# Dash python live updating table

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, dashboard

I have DatePickerRange and DataTable in my Dash, i need live-updating my DataTable when i changing my DatePickerRange.
I have code:

```
dcc.DatePickerRange(
  id = "date-picker-range",
  start_date = ("2019-3-1"),
 end_date_placeholder_text="Select a date!"
),
    dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
```

I tried:

```
mask = (df['data'] > start_date) & (df['data'] <= end_date_placeholder_text)
df.loc[mask]
```

But it doesnt work: NameError: name 'start_date' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to update your DataTable? It should be in a callback function. Without knowing more about your code and application, the structure of the callback function should be something like this:

```
#define or import 'df' here
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('table', 'data'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('date-picker-range', 'end_date_placeholder_text')])
def update_output(start_date, end_date):
    #or defined 'df' here
    mask = (df['data'] > start_date) & (df['data'] <= end_date_placeholder_text)
    return df.loc[mask].to_dict('records')
```